# How to change http method using chrome.webRequest API

Tags: google-chrome-extension, http-method, chrome-webrequest

Am using chrome.webRequest API to modify incoming requests and responses. However, I recently encountered a scenario where am required to intercept a POST call and change it to a GET call. I tried changing the method in object that I get in the callback, but in vain.

```
 chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
        function(details) { 
          details.method='GET';
            console.log('onBeforeRequest', details);
        },
        {urls: ['http://localhost/*']},
        ["requestBody"]
    );
```

Any idea what I should be doing to be able to change http method using Chrome Web Request API?

Thanks
K

Comment: Do it in onBeforeSendHeaders. Look for examples and see the documentation: your callback must return an object.

Comment: All the documentation and examples I have read thus far, only seem to talk about how to modify the http headers, but not the http method type. Am assuming Http method is not part of the http header. Please correct me if am wrong

Comment: I stand corrected, the documentation says "If the redirect is initiated at the **onHeadersReceived** stage, then the redirect will be issued using the GET method".